# Distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, distinct, amazon-redshift

I have a table with the following data:

```
Row Names  
1   George, George, John, Chris  
2   Helen, John  
3   John, John, John,John
```

and I want to make a new column with the following output

```
Row Output  
1   George, John, Chris  
2   Helen, John  
3   John
```

How can I do this in Redshift SQL

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Amazon Redshift does not support stored procedures or table functions, you should create a UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_list_dedup
(cs_list VARCHAR)
RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE AS $$
  return ','.join(set([x.strip() for x in cs_list.upper().split(',')]))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

And then call it in your query:

```
WITH cte AS 
(   
    SELECT 'George, George, John, Chris' AS Names UNION
    SELECT 'Helen, John' UNION
    SELECT 'John, John, John,John'
)
SELECT * 
, f_list_dedup(Names)
FROM cte
```